# Tomcat java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, war

I have **Tomcat 7.0.42** and Java **JDK 1.7.0_40**. Through the browser I deployed in Tomcat a **WAR** contaning just two JSP pages.
Tomcat runs as "tomcat" user and all the files in the Tomcat folder have "tomcat" as owner. Java JDK instead belongs to
the user "uucp" and group "143". In the startup script of Tomcat I added `export JAVA_HOME=/var/jdk1.7.0_40` (but if I
give the command `echo $JAVA_HOME` with user "tomcat" I get nothing).

Sometimes when I try to access the JSP pages of the deployed app I get the error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/examples] threw exception [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.test1_jsp] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.test1_jsp
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:143)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:172)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

And if I restart Tomcat, I will be able to access those JSP pages correctly and after a certain period of time the error
shows up again.

However I need to find a way to access those JSP pages correctly without the need to restart Tomcat.

Comment: i have the same issue.. im looking into it now

Answer (score 0):

- Adding JAVA_HOME will not set environment variables for the user tomcat, if you want to set it for the user, you have to define it in `.bashrc` on *nix system or in environment variable on on Windows.
- This error means tomcat can not find generated class file for your jsp page, 
  on standalone tomcat installation generated files are located on
   `/work/Catalina/localhost`
  on eclipse it will be in `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps`